# How to describe something has some property, which leads to another property

Tags: word-choice

Here is my sentence:

While A & B have identical dimensions and ***therefore*** identical mechanical properties, they may have different electrical properties.

I feel like using "therefore" here sounds not so smooth. What is the alternative way to link a property resulted from another property for something?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: 'Accordingly', they have identical properties, is another way of expressing the connection, in a less conclusory way.

Comment: "and it follows" or "consequently"

Comment: Also 'similarly', 'likewise' and 'in the same way'. I would argue that having the same dimensions does not necessarily mean having the same mechanical properties, though - wood does not have the same mechanical properties as metal.

Comment: "Perforce" might suit your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, "therefore" would be my first choice. But I can think of alternatives:

> - While A & B have identical dimensions and **thus** identical mechanical properties,
> - While A & B have identical dimensions and, **by extension**, identical mechanical properties,
> - While A & B have identical dimensions and, **subsequently**, identical mechanical properties,

I can think of more examples, but they're starting to be contrived and overly verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the word 'thus'. It is a small word and is not as cumbersome as therefore.

> While A & B have identical dimensions and **thus** identical mechanical properties, they may have different electrical properties.